# Oracle Apex Custom Function

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have created a custom function for authentication, can anyone suggest how the PARAMETERS can be passed to that particular function Using Custom Authentication Wizard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazed with no answer yet, Anyways I have sorted out myself, Here's the code for those who need it.

```
create or replace function custom_authentication (p_username in varchar2, p_password in varchar2)
return boolean
IS
begin
Your code for authentication
return true
end
```

Custom Authentication expects variable name as p_username and p_password if you are using built in login page.